# What's the difference between semicolon and double ampersand &&

Tags: shell

What is the difference between

```
echo "Hello " ; echo "world"
```

and

```
echo "Hello " && echo "world"
```

Both seems to run the two commands after each other.

Comment: In the second case, (`&&`), `echo "world"` is only executed if and only if `echo "Hello "` returns an exit status of zero.

Comment: To illustrate the difference, try `test -f /etc/passwdx && echo hello` versus `test -f /etc/passwdx ; echo hello` (you may substitute any file you want, existing or non-existing).

Comment: While I agree that the other question cited is, perhaps, technically a duplicate of this one, I contend that the *wording* of this question is *far* more useful to new users of Linux, who would not have the experience or knowledge to search for "control and redirection operators".

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Lists.html

Answer (score 284, accepted):

`echo "Hello" ; echo "world"` means sequentially run `echo "world"` no matter the exit status of the previous command `echo "Hello"`. In other words, `echo "world"` will run irrespective of success or failure of the prior command `echo "Hello"`.

In case of `echo "Hello" && echo "world"`, `echo "world"` will only run if the first command (`echo "Hello"`) is a success (i.e. exit status 0).  This is called [short circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

The following examples show how the shell handles command chaining with different operators:

```shellsession
$ false ; echo "OK"
OK
$ true ; echo "OK"
OK
$ false && echo "OK"
$ true && echo "OK"
OK
$ false || echo "OK"
OK
$ true || echo "OK"
$
```

The final case doesn't print `OK` because it was short circuited by `true`.

In short, `;` is a separator, `&&` is logical AND, `||` is logical OR (read more [here](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashSheet#Syntax)).

Comment: Nobody seems to mention that "&&" like in most programming languages means logical "and" and "||" is logical "or". The second one doesn't have to be evaluated to know that "false *and* whatever = false", so it just isn't evaluated. That's standardized behaviour of logical operators in almost all languages - the second operand is only evaluated if its true/false value makes a difference. The side effect is, that you can write stuff like `test && echo success || echo fail`.

Comment: And that common programming language behavior of halting evaluation of logical operators if the result is already determined is called ["short circuit" evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Comment: on a bitwise truthy level -- `&&` is multiplication and `||` is addition and helps to keep operation precedence straight. eg `true && false || true` is `1 * 0 + 1` and any resultant positive number is truthy; `0` is falsey

Comment: @orion But in shell, there aren’t really booleans; `false` and `true` are commands that always fail or always succeed, respectively. `&&` and `||` execution is based on exit status, not on boolean value, but it is quite analogous to “and” and “or” in other programming languages. Note that operator precedence is also different to most programming languages: `true || echo 2 && echo 1` is not grouped as `true or (print 2 and print 1)`, as (only) `1` is printed. In shell, it’s evaluated left to right instead.

Comment: the reason why there is no "OK" echo'd in the statement
true || echo "OK"
is because the || operator only evaluates up to the first true statement and doesn't eval any further.  This is called "logical short ciruiting"

Answer (score 21):

Every command in Linux returns an exit code when it finishes running. The exit code is assigned to a special variable `?`, so you can easily check the status of last command, e.g. by `echo $?`. This is often utilised in scripts. If the command finishes successfully, it returns an exit code 0, whereas if there are any errors during the execution, the exit status is non-zero. See example below:

```
$ echo "Hello"
Hello
$ echo $?
0

$ rm nonexistent-file
rm: cannot remove ‘nonexistent-file’: No such file or directory
$ echo $?
1
```

Now, this leads us to your question. The `&&` is a special operator that says 'execute the next command only if the previous command was successful, i.e. returned with an exit code of zero'. There is also a reverse operator `||`, which only executes the following command if the previous command failed, i.e. exited with non-zero. See example below:

```
$ echo "Hello" && echo "Previous command was successful"
Hello
Previous command was successful

$ rm nonexistent-file && echo "This will not be printed"
rm: cannot remove ‘nonexistent-file’: No such file or directory

$ rm nonexistent-file || echo "But this will be shown"
rm: cannot remove ‘nonexistent-file’: No such file or directory
But this will be shown
```

EDIT: The qustion was about the difference betweem `&&` and `;` so for this to be a full answer I need to add that a semicolon simply divides one command from another. No checking of the exit code takes place, so if you have several commands separated by semicolons, they are simply executed sequentially, i.e. one after another, completely independently from each other.

Comment: With a semicolon the return status is the exit status of the last command executed: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Lists.html

Answer (score 8):

In addition to [@heemayl's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/187148/3645), `&&` (and also `||`) will result in the shell only handling a *single* exit code for all the chained commands. So if you have a `trap [...] ERR` or `set -o errexit` line it will process all the commands before doing the exit code handling.