# Precedence of logical operators versus semicolon

Tags: bash, shell

What will happen if I write a line in bash like

```
commandA && commandB ; commandC
```

If `commandA` fails, will `commandC` be executed?

Comment: just in case you want both `commandB` and `commandC` (if `commandA` went OK), just write `commandA && (commandB ; commandC )`

Comment: @Archemar use curly braces to prevent sub-shell https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, and you can easily check it yourself:

```
$ non-existent-command && echo hi ; echo after semicolon
bash: non-existent-command: command not found
after semicolon
```

In `man bash` it says:

> Commands  separated  by  a  ;  are  executed sequentially;  the shell
>   waits for each command to terminate in turn.

Answer (score 3):

`commandC` will be executed no matter if `commandA` or `commandB` fails or succeeds.

Semicolon is just a separator to make commands execute sequentially. The only scenario that I can see where `commandC` will fail, is if `commandA` or `commandB` are [`exit`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html) commands (or any command like `return`/`break`/`continue`/`exec` (or functions that call those) that forcefully affects the work flow):

Scenario 1: `commandA` is `exit`

```
[root@host ~]# exit && echo "HI"; echo "test"
logout
[user@host ~]$
```

Scenario 2: `commandB` is `exit`

```
[root@host~]# echo "HI" && exit; echo "test"
HI
logout
[user@host ~]$
```

**tl;dr:** *Is not that those characters have a precedence. They mean different things. One is a logical operator and the other is a list terminator.*

**Related Stuff:**

- [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators) This answer gives a good explanation about the bash operators. Quoting a little piece of the answer:

  > - `;` : Will run one command after another has finished, irrespective of the outcome of the first.
  >
  >   ```
  >   command1 ; command2
  >   ```
  >
  >   First `command1` is run, in the foreground, and once it has finished,
  >     `command2` will be run.
  >
  >   A newline that isn't in a string literal or after certain keywords is
  >     *not* equivalent to the semicolon operator. A list of `;` delimited simple commands is still a *list* - as in the shell's parser must
  >     still continue to read in the simple commands that follow a `;`
  >     delimited simple command before executing, whereas a newline can
  >     delimit an entire command list - or list of lists. The difference is
  >     subtle, but complicated: given the shell has no previous imperative
  >     for reading in data following a newline, the newline marks a point
  >     where the shell can begin to evaluate the simple commands it has
  >     already read in, whereas a `;` semi-colon does not.
- [Semicolons superfluous at the end of a line in shell scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507038/semicolons-superfluous-at-the-end-of-a-line-in-shell-scripts) 
  Quoting the answer:

  > Single semicolons at the end of a line are superfluous, since the
  >   newline is also a command separator. `case` specifically needs double
  >   semicolons at the end of the last command in each pattern block; see
  >   `help case` for details.
- [What's the difference between semicolon and double ampersand &&](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187145/whats-the-difference-between-semicolon-and-double-ampersand)

Comment: What do you mean, “Is not that those characters have a precedence.”? `&&` (and `||`) have a higher precedence than `;` (and `|`). What do you mean, “One is for comparison and the other is to delimit where the next command on a list of commands will start (control operator).”? They are all control operators; they all delimit simple commands.

Comment: Fixed the confusion: One is a logical operator while the other is a list terminator both being control operators. But they dont have "precedence" at all, since `;` will execute no matter the outcome of what there is at left. It's a separator like `newline` on shell scripts, and its reading is somehow like natural reading: first command line sequence `;` second command line sequence `;` third command line sequenc `;` etc

Answer (score 3):

per the bash man page

> [L]ist operators, && and || have equal precedence, followed by ; and &, which have equal precedence.

In practice this boils down to who cares about the return result. If the result is need right away it has higher precedence.

Answer (score 1):

As other posts have said, the short answer is
“Yes, `commandC` will be executed regardless of what else happens.”

As [nwildner explored](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/370876/80216#370882), the longer answer is,
“Yes, `commandC` will be executed regardless of what else happens,
as long as the shell is still in a condition
in which it can execute `commandC`. 
In other words, the shell will not proceed beyond the

```
commandA && commandB ; command
```

command line without executing `commandC`.”

Trivially, if `commandA` (or `commandB`) is `kill -KILL $$`
or something else that terminates or cripples the shell,
or disrupts the command flow, then `commandC` will not be executed. 
(Clearly we’re talking about edge cases here.) 
Behavior is a little different if `set -e`
(or, equivalently, `set -o errexit`) has been issued:

- If `commandA` fails, `commandC` will be executed
  (but `commandB` will not be).
- If `commandA` succeeds, then `commandB` will be executed.

  - If `commandB` succeeds, then `commandC` will be executed.
  - If `commandB` fails, the shell will exit,
    and `commandC` will ***not*** be executed.

The `errexit` option specifies that the shell shall exit
if any command (any “pipeline”) fails, with some exceptions:

> The shell does not exit if the command that fails is
>   part of the command list immediately following a `while` or `until` keyword,
>   part of the test following the `if` or `elif` reserved words,
>   part of any command executed in a **`&&`** or **`||`** list
>   except the command following the final `&&` or `||`,
>   any command in a pipeline but the last,
>   or if the command's return value is being inverted with `!`.
>
> — from [bash(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html)

So, if `commandA` fails, that just causes `commandB` not to be executed,
because `commandA` is followed by **`&&`**. 
But if `commandB` runs and fails, it causes the shell to exit,
because it (`commandB`) follows the (final) `&&`.