# Issue with booleans tests && and || in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

Consider the following:

```
root@debian-lap:/tmp echo "Step 1 " || echo "Failed to execute step 1" ; echo "Step 2"
Step 1
Step 2
root@debian-lap:/tmp
```

As you can see, the 1st and 3rd `echo` command executed normally.

And if I the first command failed I want to  stop the script and `exit` from it:

```
root@debian-lap:/home/fugitive echo "Step 1 " || echo "Failed to execute step 1" && exit 2 ; echo "Step 2"
Step 1 
exit
fugitive@debian-lap:~$
```

The `exit` command executes and exits the shell, even thou exit code of the first command is 0. My question is - why?

In translation, doesn't this say:

- echo "Step 1"
- if the command failed , echo 'Failed to execute step 1' and exit the script
- else echo "Step 2"

Looking at this like :

`cmd foo1 || cmd foo2 && exit`

Shouldn't `cmd foo2 and (&&) exit` execute only when `cmd foo1` failed?

What I am missing?

### Edit

I am adding 2nd example, something that I am really trying to do (still dummy test)

```
root@debian-lap:/tmp/bashtest a="$(ls)" || echo "Failed" ; echo $a
test_file  # < - This is OK
root@debian-lap:


root@debian-lap:/tmp/bashtest a="$(ls)" || echo "Unable to assign the variable" && exit 2; echo $a
exit
fugitive@debian-lap:~$   # <- this is confusing part

root@debian-lap:/tmp/bashtest a="$(ls /tmpppp/notexist)" || echo "Unable to assign the variable" ; echo $a
ls: cannot access /tmpppp/notexist: No such file or directory
Unable to assign the variable            # <- This is also OK
root@debian-lap:
```

Comment: Related: [Precedence of logical operators versus semicolon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/370876/precedence-of-logical-operators-versus-semicolon)

Comment: You should **really** add a `\$ ` to the end of your `$PS1` value.

Comment: @Wildcard I've removed due snippets, ofc it is included. As commands I've shown are executed in root, the `#` makes rest of the line commented out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the last command executed (the `echo`) succeeded. If you want to group the commands, it's clearer to use an `if` statement:

```
if ! step 1 ; then
   echo >&2 "Failed to execute step 1"
   exit 2
fi
```

You could also group the error message and exit with `{ ... }` but that's somewhat harder to read. However that does preserve the exact value of the exit status.

```
step 1 || { echo >&2 "step 1 failed with code: $?"; exit 2; }
```

Note, I changed the `&&` to a semicolon, since I assume you want to exit even if the error message fails (and output those errors on stderr for good practice).

For the `if` variant to preserve the exit status, you'd need to add your code to the `else` part:

```
if step 1; then
  : OK, do nothing
else
  echo >&2 "step 1 failed with code: $?"
  exit 2
fi
```

(that also makes it compatible with the Bourne shell that didn't have the `!` keyword).

---

As or why the commands group like the do, the [standard says](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_03):

> An AND-OR list is a sequence of one or more pipelines separated by the operators `"&&"` and `"||"`.
>
> The operators `"&&"` and `"||"` shall have equal precedence and shall be evaluated with left associativity.

Which means that something like `somecmd || echo && exit` acts as if `somecmd` and `echo` were grouped together first, i.e.  `{ somecmd || echo; } && exit` and not  `somecmd || { echo && exit; }` .

Comment: But how the 2nd echo succeeded when I've declared `||` after the first command ? Thats what confuses me :)

Comment: @fugitive, edited to elaborate on that

Comment: Also, note that `A && B || C` is **not** the same as `if A; then B; else C; fi` when we are think about what happens if A succeeds but B fails. I'd recommend to stick with the `if` command to avoid confusion and ambiguity.

Comment: @ilkkachu Thanks man for explanation, now it makes sense!
@glennjackman thanks, I know that this is bad example, and `if` is better but wanted to troubleshoot this. :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem lies in the priority of binary/logical operators. Namely "and" and "or" have the same priority, and as such the following line: 
 `echo "Step 1 " || echo "Failed to execute step 1" && exit 2 ; echo "Step 2"` is essentially  the same as: 
 `( echo "Step 1 " || echo "Failed to execute step 1" ) && exit 2 ; echo "Step 2"`. 
 You should try `echo "Step 1 " || ( echo "Failed to execute step 1" && exit 2 ) ; echo "Step 2"` instead.