# How linux determines the order of operation in commands performing combined redirections?

Tags: linux, grep, io-redirection

As we are aware that, from the following command, output of `less --help | grep -i examine` is redirected to the file **examine-files-in-less**, Is there any generic order of operation used by linux similar to `BODMAS rule` that we have in mathematics?

```
less --help | grep -i examine > examine-files-in-less
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All commands involved in a pipeline such as the one in the question are started (pretty much) at the same time.

This means that the commands in a pipeline such as

```
find . ...some other arguments... | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

are all running in parallel.

However, since the output of one command is the input to the next, and since commands wait for input to be delivered and for output to be consumed, the data synchronizes the commands in the pipeline.

In the above pipeline, for example, the last `sort` will be running, but won't do much until all the output of `find` has been consumed by the first `sort` (a sorting operation requires that *all* available data has been read).

The data, hence, enforces a left-to-right ordering in the *processing* done by the pipeline.

In other compound commands, such as the list

```
ls -l; cat somefile
```

which is the same as

```
ls -l
cat somefile
```

there is a strict left-to-right ordering. `cat` will not start until `ls` has finished.

In a compound command such as

```
test -f filename || echo 'no such file'
```

there is also a strict left-to-right ordering, and here, `echo` will not execute if `test` returns a zero exit status.

See also, for example, "[Issue with booleans tests && and || in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/372199/issue-with-booleans-tests-and-in-bash)" and "[Precedence of logical operators versus semicolon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/370876/precedence-of-logical-operators-versus-semicolon)".