# Why doesn't using multiple commands with a || or && conditional work?

Tags: shell-script, arguments

This works on a shell (bash, dash) prompt:

```sh
[ -z "" ] && echo A || echo B
A
```

However, I am trying to write a [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) shell script, it starts like this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

[ "${#}" -eq 1 ] || echo "Invalid number of arguments, expected one."; exit 1

readonly raw_input_string=${1}

[ -z "${raw_input_string}" ] && echo "The given argument is empty."; exit 1
```

And I don't know why, but I **don't get the message**:

> The given argument is empty.

if I call the script like this:

```sh
./test_empty_argument ""
```

Why is that?

Comment: See [How can I test if a variable is empty or contains only spaces?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/146942/170373) for ways on testing if a variable is empty, unset, or only contains blanks. The issue in this question has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Just use `if [ X”” = X”$var” ] ; then echo isempty ; fi`

Comment: @user2497 There is no reason to use that in any shell released in the last 20 years. That's a workaround for old, buggy shells.

Comment: @chepner So it is not a valid solution? Something else must be used?

Comment: `[ "" = "$var" ]` would work fine; a quoted empty string will not be removed from the argument list of `[`. But that's not necessary either, because `[ -z "$var" ]` *also* works just fine.

Comment: @chepner Yes, the first is nice. I used `-z` but some version or fork of pdksh gave me errors. Incidentally, it is ~20 years old, thanks for clearing this up.

Comment: Why is this getting off-topic votes, when it's more of a duplicate of ilkkachu's linked question ?????

Comment: @user2497, ...the shells that give you trouble with `[ -z "" ]` are *not* POSIX-compliant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Precedence of logical operators versus semicolon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/370876/precedence-of-logical-operators-versus-semicolon)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Note that your line

```
[ "${#}" -eq 1 ] || echo "Invalid number of arguments, expected one."; exit 1
```

this is the same as

```
[ "${#}" -eq 1 ] || echo "Invalid number of arguments, expected one."
exit 1
```

(an unquoted `;` can, in most circumstances, be replaced by a newline character)

This means that the `exit 1` statement is always executed regardless of how many arguments were passed to the script.  This in turn means that the message `The given argument is empty.` would never have a chance of getting printed.

To execute more than a single statement after a test using the "short-circuit syntax", group the statements in `{ ...; }`. The alternative is to use a proper `if` statement (which, IMHO, looks cleaner in a script):

```
if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
    echo 'Invalid number of arguments, expected one.' >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

You have the same issue with your second test.

---

Regarding

```
[ -z "" ] && echo A || echo B
```

This would work for the given example, but the generic

```
some-test && command1 || command2
```

would *not* be the same as

```
if some-test; then
    command1
else
    command2
fi
```

Instead, it is more like

```
if ! { some-test && command1; }; then
    command2
fi
```

or

```
if some-test && command1; then
    :
else
    command2
fi
```

That is, if either the test or the first command fails, the second command executes, which means it has the potential to execute *all three* involved statements.

Answer (score 17):

This:

```
[ "${#}" -eq 1 ] || echo "Invalid number of arguments, expected one."; exit 1
```

is not:

```
[ "${#}" -eq 1 ] || { echo "Invalid number of arguments, expected one."; exit 1; }
```

But instead is:

```
{ [ "${#}" -eq 1 ] || echo "Invalid number of arguments, expected one."; } 
exit 1
```

Your script is exiting regardless of how many arguments you passed to it.

Answer (score 8):

One way to make it more readable is to define a `die` function (à la `perl`) like:

```
die() {
  printf >&2 '%s\n' "$@"
  exit 1
}

# then:

[ "$#" -eq 1 ] || die "Expected one argument, got $#"

[ -n "$1" ] || die "Empty argument not supported"
```

You can add more bells and whistles like colours, prefix, line number... if need be.

Comment: In practice, do you ever call your `die` function with multiple arguments? (If so, can you give an example?)  I use an almost identical `die` function, but use `"$*"` instead, which may be more what you're intending?

Comment: The value of `"$@"` is that it allows multi-line messages without needing to add literal newlines.

Comment: @jrw32982, using `"$*"` to join args with spaces also means you need to set `$IFS` to SPC for it to work in all contexts including those where `$IFS` has been modified. Alternatively with `ksh`/`zsh`, you can use `print -r -- "$@"` or `echo -E - "$@"` in `zsh`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, but I've **never** seen that done in the context of a `die`-type function.  What I'm asking is: in practice, have you ever seen anyone write `die "unable to blah:" "some error"`, for the purpose of getting a 2-line error message?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Good point.  So (in my formulation) it should be `die() { IFS=" "; printf >&2 "%s\n" "$*"; exit 1; }`.  Have you ever personally used this kind of `die` function to have `printf` generate a multi-line error message by passing multiple arguments?  Or do you only ever pass a single argument to `die` so that it only adds a single newline to its output?

Comment: @jrw32982, I have, rarely. That's why I use `"$@"` instead of `"$1"`. Generally I call `die` with one argument (so `"$1"`, `"$*"`, `"$@"` would make no difference). `perl`'s `die()` does `"$*"` with empty `$IFS` (concatenates the arguments without separator). I sometimes use `die() { [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf...` so that `die` without argument acts like `exit 1`.

Comment: @jrw32982, I've certainly written multi-line error messages that way myself in real, production code.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I've found it to be more readable to use `<<` here-strings which include their newlines literally.  I'm curious about the use case when several strings without newlines is better than one here-string with embedded newlines.

Answer (score -1):

I've often seen this as a test for an empty string:

```
if [ "x$foo" = "x" ]; then ...
```

Comment: Should have been "=" - fixed.

Comment: That practice is literally from the 1970s. There is no reason whatsoever to use it with any shell that is compliant with the 1992 POSIX sh standard (so long as correct quoting is used and now-obsolescent functionality such as `-a`, `-o`, `(` and `)` as derectives to tell `test` to combine multiple operations in a single invocation are avoided; see the OB markers in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html).

Comment: Non-linux unices shipped with the original 'sh' well into the '90's - maybe still do. In my job at that time, I had to write portable install scripts and I used this construct. I just looked at the install scripts that NVidia ships for linux and they still use this construct.

Comment: NVidia may use it, but that's not to say they have any technical justification to do so; cargo-cult development in commercial UNIX is sadly prevalent. Even [Heirloom Bourne](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/sh.html) doesn't have the bug in question -- so the SunOS codebase (that being the last commercial UNIX to ship a non-POSIX `/bin/sh`, and Heirloom Bourne's immediate predecessor) didn't have it either.

Comment: I don't wear a hat, so I can't promise to post a YouTube video eating it should someone turn up a shell published on a commercial UNIX with this bug post-1990... but if I did, it would be tempting. :)